# Converting String to Date in Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe (`df1`) with 2 `StringType` fields.

Field1 (StringType) Value-`X`

Field2 (StringType) value-`20180101`

All I am trying to do is create another dataframe (`df2`) from `df1` with 2 fields-

Field1 (StringType) Value-`X`

Field2 (Date Type) Value-`2018-01-01`

I am using the below code-

```
df2=df1.select(
     col("field1").alias("f1"),
     unix_timestamp(col("field2"),"yyyyMMdd").alias("f2")
)

df2.show

df2.printSchema
```

For this field 2, I tried multiple things - `unix_timestamp` , `from_unixtimestamp`, `to_date`, `cast(“date”)` but nothing worked

I need the following schema as output:

```
df2.printSchema
|-- f1: string (nullable = false)
|-- f2: date (nullable = false)
```

I'm using Spark 2.1

Answer (score 4):

`to_date` seems to work fine for what you need:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df1 = Seq( ("X", "20180101"), ("Y", "20180406") ).toDF("c1", "c2")

val df2 = df1.withColumn("c2", to_date($"c2", "yyyyMMdd"))

df2.show
// +---+----------+
// | c1|        c2|
// +---+----------+
// |  X|2018-01-01|
// |  Y|2018-04-06|
// +---+----------+

df2.printSchema
// root
//  |-- c1: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- c2: date (nullable = true)
```

[UPDATE]

For Spark 2.1 or prior, `to_date` doesn't take format string as a parameter, hence explicit string formatting to the standard `yyyy-MM-dd` format using, say, `regexp_replace` is needed:

```
val df2 = df1.withColumn(
  "c2", to_date(regexp_replace($"c2", "(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", "$1-$2-$3"))
)
```

Comment: Hi Leo, thanks for your answer. I tried that option as well before but it tells me “too many arguments for the method to_date”. is it because of diff versions we are running on. i am using Spark 2.1.0. Are you using a later version?

Comment: @Sidd, you're right that `to_date` in Spark 2.1 or prior takes only a single parameter.  Please see my expanded answer for a work-around.